# Angular Test within Subscribe block not running

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to test a service in Angular, but I cannot get into the subscribe block of the service, and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {

  getNowPlaying() {
    return this.http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=[MY KEY]&language=en&region=US').switchMap(res => {
      const page = Math.ceil(res['total_pages'] * Math.random());
      return this.http.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=[MY KEY]&language=en&region=US&page=${page}`);
    });
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

}
```

And my test:

```
describe('getNowPlaying', () => {
    it('should get a page of now playing movies from the api', async(
      inject([MovieService, HttpTestingController], (movieService: MovieService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
        movieService.getNowPlaying().subscribe(res => {
          console.log('hi');
        });

        backend.expectOne({
          url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=[MY KEY]&language=en&region=US',
          method: 'GET'
        });
      }),
    ));
})
```

The backend.expectOne test passes, but I am just trying to log 'hi' to the console to show I am getting into the subscribe block, and nothing logs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to see whatever code you have inside of the subscribe block, because as with the case of setTimeout this code will be working asynchronously. Angular has great out-of-the-box tools to deal with asynchronous test: `async` and `fakeasync`.

Simply wrap your whole `it` case into `fakeasync` and use `tick()` if you need to wait for some async operation to complete. You will find an example in this article: https://medium.com/@paynoattn/simple-observable-unit-testing-in-angular2-43c4f4a0bfe2

**UPDATE**
If you need to see what was returned from the API call you can simply declare a variable outside of the subscribe block and inside of it assign the response to it. Then log it.

```
it('should get a page of now playing movies from the api', fakeAsync(
  inject([MovieService, HttpTestingController], (movieService: MovieService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
    let response;

    movieService.getNowPlaying().subscribe(res => {
      response = res;
    });
    tick();

    expect(response).toEqual(...);

    backend.expectOne({
      url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=[MY KEY]&language=en&region=US',
      method: 'GET'
    });
  }),
));
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it's already wrapped in async(). I've also tried with fakeAsync and tick() with no success.

Comment: With the included answer the test fails. I expected the response toBeDefined, but it says it's expecting undefined to be defined